# How to encode and decode HexAccountSting to AccountID in golang

Tags: golang, ss58format

How can we  encode the accountID  **'5FLSigC9HGRKVhB9FiEo4Y3koPsNmBmLJbpXg2mp1hXcS59Y'**
to Hex string using golang for posting in RPC.

Comment: There you go: `0x90b5ab205c6974c9ea841be688864633dc9ca8a357843eeacf2314649965fe22` :)

Comment: @AdamWierzbicki, I need sample code in golang to do this. I can convert this using online tool.

Comment: Alright, got you. Please check out the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [go-subkey](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vedhavyas/go-subkey) for this purpose. I don't know Go very well, but I think the code to transform accountID into hex string would look like this.

```go
import (
    "github.com/vedhavyas/go-subkey/v2"
)

addr := "5FLSigC9HGRKVhB9FiEo4Y3koPsNmBmLJbpXg2mp1hXcS59Y"
_, pubkeyBytes, err := subkey.SS58Decode(addr)
// Handle err somehow
hexString := subkey.EncodeHex(pubkeyBytes)
```